# OkHttp: separate Connection Pools for single domains. Is it a good idea?

Tags: java, connection, okhttp, pool

I use the OkHttp library in my Java application. This application makes a lot of API calls to different external services, but most of the calls are made on the same domains, like this:

- DOMAIN 1, about 55% of the total calls
- DOMAIN 2, about 35% of the total calls
- OTHER DOMAINS, about 10% of the total calls

At the moment I have three separate `ConnectionPool` objects, with the corresponding `OkHttpClient` object. If I understood correctly, the point of a `ConnectionPool` is to keep connections alive in order to be reused when a second request to the same domain is made. So in my mind it makes sense to have separate connection pools for those domains where I know I make a lot of requests (I do about 1.000 calls / minute), but online I found this:

> Applications should avoid creating many connection pools as doing so
> prevents connection reuse. Each connection pool holds its own set of
> connections alive so applications that have many pools also risk
> exhausting memory!
>
> The best practice in OkHttp 3 is to create a single OkHttpClient
> instance and share it throughout the application. Requests that needs
> a customized client should call OkHttpClient.newBuilder() on that
> shared instance. This allows customization without the drawbacks of
> separate connection pools.

So my question is: should I change my code and reuse the same object for every request, or is it okay to keep it the way I'm doing? Also, which could be a good THREADS_NUMBER to start with? I'm currently using about 60 threads for every pool and not having any issue, but I'd like to know if there is a "formula" to calculate a more precise / recommended number.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes - you should generally use the same connection pool.  Can you also expand on whether you are using HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2?  For thread count - you should benchmark at different values.

Comment: Thanks @YuriSchimke! I'm mainly using HTTP/2 (some requests may be HTTP/1.1, but a small number). So I could start for example with 500 threads and see how it goes? My application already uses about 500 threads to do its work, so that brings the total count of threads at (at most) about a thousand. But I also need it to be able to answer fast if there is any spike in requests. I will definitely do some benchmarks, thanks

Comment: It will share those threads to execute requests, and with HTTP/2 you might actually find it's sharing those down to 3 connections, so 500 is overkill.  Hence benchmark.  You can get log output on what threads are doing, and event listener for tracing calls.